# ServiceStack OrmLite generic database search

Tags: ormlite-servicestack

I need simple search functionality in different tables through my application, so I was thinking creating a `GenericFilter` class, passing a query and some conditions and return the results in some way.

Is it possible with OrmLite to return such a list, or another structure? An example would be:

```
var result = db.Sel???("select ID, FirstName, LastName from Customers where City='Paris'");
```

The result could be anything, from a `DataTable` to an `array`. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at OrmLite's [support for Dynamic Result Sets](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets) which for adhoc queries you can return C# 7 tuples, a `List<object>`

```
List<List<object>> result = db.SqlList<List<object>>("SELECT ...");
```

Or have each row populate a Dictionary with their column names:

```
var results = db.SqlList<Dictionary<string,object>>("SELECT ...");
```

You can also use `dynamic`:

```
var results = db.SqlList<dynamic>("SELECT ...");
```

Should you need it, ServiceStack has great support for populating Types [to and from Dictionary Objects](http://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary) into any POCO Type.

Comment: Thanks! it is exactly what I wanted.